# Pasar un procedimiento almacenado de SQL a JSON

Tags: sql, sql-server, json, sql-server-2008, microsoft

Buenas tardes comunidad,

Queria saber si hay alguna forma de pasar/transformar sentencias sql o procedimientos almacenados en lenguaje sql    en scripts de JSON.

Si me indicais foros, sean en español o en inglés, con está temática, os lo agradecería un montón.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow, que es lo que buscas excatamente una forma de hacerlo por código o alguna web/programa? si es lo segundo google literalmente es tu amigo ya que el primer resultado ya te resuelve el problema

Comment: Me han solicitado pasar informes que se hacen normalmente con SQL a formato tipo JSON.  Como esta migración es urgente, y sé poco de JSON, me preguntaba si había algún programa/ web o algún foro que trate una temática similar a la mía. Sería de mucha ayuda.  Siento las molestias.

Comment: Puedes mirar en este [link](https://www.sqlshack.com/es/convertir-resultados-de-sql-server-json/) que te explica como hacerlo, en resumen es anadir al final de tu consulta `FOR JSON AUTO` (por ejemplo) esto te devuelve el resultado en formato JSON lo copias y vas a la tipica pagina para formatear los jsons [link](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com). Si esta informacion te ayuda avisame y luego lo pongo como respuesta

Comment: Lo que comenta @Capt.Teach solo funciona en versiones posteriores a 2016. Para versiones previas, puedes usar [la solución que creó Phil Factor](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/producing-json-documents-from-sql-server-queries-via-tsql/).

Comment: Yo por ejemplo quiero transformar esta sentencia   **cast (case when [tipo_genero]='V' then [genero] else '' end as varchar(2)) AS genero**  es decir como pasar ese comando en "comandos"  de JSON .  Que libro recomendais para aprender JSON. Un saludo

Comment: @LuisCazares Es verdad, error mio de no especificar que SQL Server estoy usando, es la version de 2008.

Comment: Hasta donde sé, JSON no tiene comandos. Es básicamente un formato con funcionalidad similar al XML. Según el programa que los consuma será su funcionalidad, pero no hay un estándar para definir que hará cada etiqueta.